# Is there a way to use ReactNative library in Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I worked on a React Native library and we build some native functionality like implementing BLE. So we did that in Android and iOS folders under React Native. Now we want to use the same functionality in Native project iOS and Android (Native). Reason we built in React Native is coz we have a different project thats in React Native. But now we are trying to use this library in native projects. We are not sure how we can achieve that.

We don't have anything built in this Library other than in Android and iOS folders under RN project.[image]

Attaching image of how we build or functionality in React Native but under Android and iOS folders. (We can just copy pate and create a native library but trying to avoid that).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. you probably have to separate them to 2 different libraries and publish them independently